# How do I create a bib file in texlipse?

Tags: bibtex, texlipse

This seems like it should be really straightforward, but I can't figure it out. When I go to <kbd>File</kbd>→<kbd>New</kbd> there is no `.bib` file. Under <kbd>File</kbd>→<kbd>New</kbd>→<kbd>Other</kbd>→<kbd>Texlipse</kbd> there is no `.bib` file.

Is there somewhere else that I should be looking to create this?

Answer (score 1):

You can save the new file with the extension bib and after this you can work like described at the user manual: http://texlipse.sourceforge.net/manual/bibtex.html